# htaccess - remove “index.php” from URL and redirect with exclusion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have read a lot of answers on this site, but didn't find a working example. Therefore, I decided to ask my question.

How can I make a redirect from a file (index.php(.htm /.html / etc.) with exclusion?

For example, I have a link #1: "/dir1/some-text_index.php" and link #2: /dir1/index.php.
What rule should be set to link #1 - redirect doesn't happen, and link #2 occurred redirect, ie:

```
/dir1/some-text_index.php -> /dir1/some-text_index.php - nothing to do
/dir1/index.php -> /dir1/ - redirect
```

and more examples:

```
/dir1/some-text_index.php/dir2 -> /dir1/some-text_index.php/dir2 - nothing to do
/dir1/index.php/dir2 -> /dir1/dir2 - redirect
/dir1/some-text_index.php/dir2/?param=value -> /dir1/some-text_index.php/dir2/?param=value - nothing to do
/dir1/index.php/dir2/?param=value -> /dir1/dir2/?param=value - redirect
```

Thanks all for yours attention.

Comment: When you open `http://domain.com/dir1/dir2` does it load correct content?

Comment: Why this question? How does this relate to my question? Yes, everything appears correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
```